# Why would fish appear to ignore the second 'set' command in a function?

Tags: fish

When I run this function, JAVA_HOME gets set, JUG_BT_ARCH does not get set, and 'gello' gets echoed. I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious.

```
function j8
  set -x JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/
  set -x JUG_BT_ARCH amd64-darwin11-xcode4
  echo gello
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables by default have function-scope, so when the function ends, they go away. You can make them global via `--global` or `-g`:

```
set -gx JUG_BT_ARCH amd64-darwin11-xcode4
```

Now when you run the function, this variable will stick around.

Comment: I get it, my environment previously set -g for JAVA_HOME before I run the function.